# How to run the same job with two different agents with Declarative Syntax?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two jobs running on two different OS, all the build steps are the same, it is the tools (jdk and maven), the meta data that are different.

I want to make a job that include both jobs on two agents depending on the OS.
I'm using Jenkins Pipeline Declarative Syntax, the problem is that I couldn't find a way to declare tools for a specific `agent`.

In Jenkins Pipeline, we can declare `tools` inside the entire pipeline or inside a specific `stage` and that's it.

PS: I need to use the declarative Syntax: no use of `node {}`

If I do so:

```groovy
stage('Environment Set Up Linux') {
    agent {
        label "linux"
    }
    tools {
        jdk 'oracle-jdk-1.8'
    }
    steps {
        echo "Environment tools have been configured"
    }
}

stage('Environment Set Up Solaris') {
    agent {
        label "solaris-64"
    }
    tools {
        jdk 'oracle-jdk-1.7'
    }
    steps {
        echo "Environment tools have been configured"
    }
}
```

The tools will be used only for those stages not all stages and making tools in every stage would be stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Define the common tools which are available on every slave in the entire pipeline and the specific ones in the stage section:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.3.9' 
    }


    stages {
        stage('test'){
            tools {
                maven 'Maven 2.2.1' 
            }

            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }

        stage('random'){
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the output in the stage 'test' is 2.2.1 because I define my tools in the stage section which overwrites the global pipeline. In the stage random I define no tools inside the stage so the tools which are defined in the global pipeline are used and 3.3.9 is printed. I hope this is what you meant.

In your case it could be all agents contain jdk1.8 and you want to use it in nearly ever stage (define it in the pipeline), if there is one stage in which you want to use jdk 1.7, just define the tools in the stage section which will overwrite the global config.